# Angular Bootstrap Alert w/ ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying an alert message based upon a $scope value ("0" or "1") and ng-hide. The alert displays correctly when the page loads, but when the $scope value is updated, the corresponding view is not.

Angular bootstrap alert has a "close" directive that Im using to update the $scope value (from "0" to "1") - hoping that ng-hide would automatically hide it. I can see that the value is being updated from "0" to "1" but the view is not being update.

Ive tried $scope.apply and $scope.digest but both result in an error.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ECPfyNcWAzIvfFFoRJ1C?p=preview)

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">

  <div style="margin-top:100px" ng-hide="{{error_accountsuspended}}">
    <alert type="danger" close="closeAlert('1')">{{error_accountsuspended_msg}}</alert>
</div>

</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AlertDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {

 $scope.error_accountsuspended=0;

 $scope.error_accountsuspended_msg="Your Account is Suspended";

  $scope.closeAlert = function(alerttype) {

    if(alerttype==1){
       $scope.error_accountsuspended=1;

    }

  };
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need the brackets:

```
    <div style="margin-top:100px" ng-hide="error_accountsuspended">
```

this works fine for me in your plunker

Comment: Wow - first off thanks! Second, it really sucks to think about how much time I wasted on this. Everything works now!